# Не меняется bool значение или я не правильно его пытаюсь изменить/прочитать

Tags: c#

хочу, чтобы success менялся на true или false в зависимости от ответа api.
Код:

```
    private bool success;

    private void VKMessage(string msg) {
        string url = "https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?user_id=" + config.ID + "&message=" + msg + "&v=5.68&access_token=" + config.Token;
        string type = "message"; 
        webrequest.Enqueue(url, null, (code, response) => GetCallback(code, response, type), this);
    }

    private void VKGroupPost(string msg) {
        string url = "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?owner_id=-" + config.Group + "&message=" + msg + "&from_group=1&v=5.68&access_token=" + config.Token;
        string type = "post"; 
        webrequest.Enqueue(url, null, (code, response) => GetCallback(code, response, type), this);
    }
    private void VKGroupStatus(string msg) {
        string url = "https://api.vk.com/method/status.set?group_id=" + config.Group + "&text=" + msg + "&v=5.68&access_token=" + config.Token;
        string type = "status"; 
        webrequest.Enqueue(url, null, (code, response) => GetCallback(code, response, type), this);
    }

    void GetCallback(int code, string response, string type) {
        if(!response.Contains("error"))
        {
            success = true;
        } else {
            success = false;
        }
    }

    [ConsoleCommand("vk")]
    void vk(ConsoleSystem.Arg args) {   
        if(args.Args[0].ToLower() == "status") {
            if(args.Args[1].ToLower() == "set") {
                string status = "";
                for (int i = 2; i < args.Args.Length; i++)
                    status += args.Args[i] + " ";
                VKGroupStatus(Uri.EscapeDataString(status));
                if(success == true) {
                    PrintWarning("Status \"" + status + "\" was success set");
                } else {
                    PrintError("Status \"" + status + "\" can't be set");
                }
            }
        } else 

        if(args.Args[0].ToLower() == "post") {              
            string post = "";
            for (int i = 1; i < args.Args.Length; i++)
                post += args.Args[i] + " ";
            VKGroupPost(Uri.EscapeDataString(post));
            if(success == true) {
                PrintWarning("Post \"" + post + "\" was success posted on the wall");
            } else {
                PrintError("Post \"" + post + "\" can't be posted on the wall");
            }
        } else

        if(args.Args[0].ToLower() == "message") {               
            string message = "";
            for (int i = 1; i < args.Args.Length; i++)
                message += args.Args[i] + " ";              
            VKMessage(Uri.EscapeDataString(message));
            if(success == true) {
                PrintWarning("Message \"" + message + "\" was success sent");
            } else {
                PrintError("Message \"" + message + "\" can't be sent");
            }

        } 
    }
```

Однако при таком коде если ввести в консоли команду vk message test, то сообщение уходит в ВК, но ответ получаю Message "test" can't be sent, а должно быть Message "test" success sent. Где у меня ошибка?

UPDATE:
Заметил, что если выполнить одну и ту же команду (можно менять текст), т.е.:
`vk message text1` - будет false
все последующие команды
`vk message text2`
`vk message text3` и т.д. будут true

Comment: Хочу заметить, что Вконтакте официально ограничивают доступ к API сообщений. Также приношу извинения за оффтоп, но я думаю, что проще будет работать с вк, через вот эту либу: https://www.nuget.org/packages/VkNet/

Comment: @alladuh ограничивает, но работать вроде будет можно чуть иначе. Это в целом не важно в рамках текущего вопроса. По поводу работы с вк - мне не совсем понятно зачем для трех-пяти задач использовать какую-то либу, если можно написать код более легкий и быстрый без лишних методов, которыми я не собираюсь пользоваться. :) Однако спасибо за Ваш ответ.

Comment: Кто-то может помочь мне с этим вопросом?

Answer (score 0):

```
   if(!response.Contains("error"))
   {
        /*bool*/ success = true;
   } else {
        /*bool*/ success = false;
   }
```

или

```
   success = !response.Contains("error");
```

Comment: это было первое, что я попробовал. :)
Вернее так было написано, bool я уже написал от безысходности. :(

Так не работает.

Comment: По поводу "success = !response.Contains("error")" - АПИ не отдает в ответе bool значение типа true или false, там json вида {response: "4241"} - при успехе и {error....} при ошибке